# Xamarin form: Can Add tabs in Shell App programmatically on the contentpage

Tags: shell, xamarin.forms, tabs

I finding through the google but could not find the result.

I have a Shell setup Xamarin form application. Eventhough I am not fully use it's functionally but there is a tab setup in xaml file.

I am wonder can i have a content page hosted under the shellContent and add Tabs from the contentPage.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to achieve it like this GIF?

[image]

You can add x:Name for `TabBar` in `AppShell.xml` like this code.

```
   <TabBar x:Name="myTabBars">
        <Tab Title="Browse" Icon="tab_feed.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="About" Icon="tab_about.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
```

In the `AppShell.xml.cs`, expose this tabbar.

```
   public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
    {
        //  public static Shell myshell;
        public static TabBar mytabbar;
        public AppShell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

             mytabbar = myTabBars;


        }
    }
```

Use it in the `ContentPage`.

```
       private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            ShellSection shell_section = new ShellSection
            {
                Title = "home",

            };

            shell_section.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Content = new HomePage() });
            AppShell.mytabbar.Items.Add(shell_section);

        }
```

Comment: yes. but do i need to remove when going back to previous screen or routing to other screen

Comment: @LittleFunny Can you explain your needs more clearly? And if the reply is helpful, please do not forget to mark it as answer.