# How to add two pages in xamarin.forms shell in code behind

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to add dynamically two pages (ShellContents) into my LoginShell, but `LoginShell.Current` is always null?

```
    {
        public LoginShell(string page = null)
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            ShellItem si = new ShellItem();


            LoginShell.Current.Items.FirstOrDefault().Items.Add(new ShellContent {ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(SignUpPage))});

        }
    }
```

LoginShell.Current is a read-only property.

**Update**

I implemented following code for my StartUpShell class:

```
    public partial class StartUpShell : Shell
    {
        public StartUpShell(string page)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ShellContent content;

            if(page == nameof(SignUpPage))
            {
               content = new SignUpPage();
            }
            else if(page == nameof(LoginPinPage))
            {
                content = new LoginPinPage();
            }
            else
            {
                content = new SignUpPage();
            }

            ShellSection shellSection = new ShellSection();
            shellSection.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Content = content });

            CurrentItem = shellSection;
        }
```

but on when I set content variable it crashes with a message: 
`ShellContent Content should be of type Page. Title , Route D_FAULT_ShellContent4`

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do this in C#, you could try the code below.

```
public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ShellSection shell_section = new ShellSection
        {
            Title = "home",
        };

        shell_section.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Content = new ItemsPage() });

        ShellSection shell_section1 = new ShellSection
        {
            Title = "about",


        };

        shell_section1.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Content = new AboutPage() });

        myshell.Items.Add(shell_section);
        myshell.Items.Add(shell_section1);
    }
}
```

`x:Name="myshell"` is the name of `Shell`.

Here is running GIF.

[image]

**update**

If you type of LoginShell is `Xamarin.Forms.Shell`, You want to replace current page with your needs, you can use following code.

```
    public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
    {
        public AppShell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();



            ShellSection shell_section1 = new ShellSection
            {
                Title = "Page1",


            };

            shell_section1.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Content = new Page1() });

            CurrentItem = shell_section1;



        }
    }
```

Here is running screenshot.

[image]

If you want to hide the navigation bar. you can add `Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false"` in your ContentPage. Here is code about adding it in page1.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
            Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false"
             x:Class="App18.Views.Page1">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

[image]

Comment: @Stefan89BEG Do you have any update for this issue?

Comment: You have copied solution from another stackoverflow thread. I dont want flyout menu, just I want one page which source will be binding to the sopecific page depends of input arg from constructor.

Comment: What is your type of the `LoginShell`? Is `Xamarin.Forms.Shell`?

Comment: Where do you want to add two pages? In TabBar? If it like this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/60522174/10627299

Comment: @Stefan89BEG If the answer is helpful, please mark it (click the "✔" at the top right corner of this answer ), it will help others who have similar issues.

Comment: Lu  I have an error when I try to set content for ShellContent. Please see my updated question

Comment: type of content is shellcontent , it may be wrong ,you should set it type is contentpage

Comment: I set it up as Page and it works. And how can I call another shell page, for example PostShellPage in my viewmodel?

Comment: but I have now exception when Im trying to `await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync( new SentEmailPage());`` Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at Xamarin.Forms.ShellSection.OnPushAsync`

Comment: If you have another issue, you can open a new thread(please keep one thread for one question ), I have out of office, I can not test it for you.

Comment: yes, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906952/xamarin-forms-navigation-pushasync-not-working/61251772#61251772

Comment: this solution doesnt work, because its throw null reference exception from the navigated page.

Comment: Please update a demo, I cannot reproduce your issue.